# How to set Cache-control: private with applicationContext.xml in Spring 4.2 or later

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, caching

How to set Cache-control: private with applicationContext.xml in Spring 4.2 or later?

## Background:

`Cache-control:` HTTP headers can be set from `applicationContext.xml` in Spring 4.1 like this:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
    <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
    <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
    <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
  </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

There are some annotation-based implementations like https://github.com/foo4u/spring-mvc-cache-control , but I prefer XML based configuration because I have to change HTTP headers according to testing/production environment (e.g. Chrome sends another request for "View page source" if the page returned with `Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate`, and make anti-CSRF tokens unmatch).

## Problem:

These settings are deprecated as of Spring 4.2.
Additionally, `Cache-control: private` cannot be set from these settings. Because some CDN provider do not store contents if and only if http header contaings `Cache-Control: private`, the support for this HTTP header is critical for the system that uses CDNs. e.g. http://tech.mercari.com/entry/2017/06/22/204500 or https://community.fastly.com/t/fastly-ttl/882 .

So I am looking for the way to set Cache-Control: private HTTP header from `applicationContext.xml` for the sake of safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be there is no XML out-of-the-box support in Spring 4.2+. As you can see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/WebContentInterceptor.java), there is no `set` method for `cacheControlMappings` of `WebContentInterceptor`, so there is no chance to write values from XML configuration into it; and this map is intended to store url-cache-control mappings. However, [`CacheControl`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/CacheControl.java) class has public `cachePrivate` method, that is possible to be used for registering custom configurations (I think that could be done with respect to dev or prod profiles); for example:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    CacheControl cacheControl = CacheControl.empty().cachePrivate();
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .setCacheControl(cacheControl);
}
```

Or directly in your controller (could be dependent on active profile too):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public ResponseEntity<?> doHandleRequest () {
    CacheControl cacheControl = CacheControl.empty().cachePrivate();
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                         .cacheControl(cacheControl);
}
```

If you certainly need to utilize XML configuration, nobody prevents you from writing custom subclass of `WebContentInterceptor` with appropriate methods and logic, luckily, `WebContentInterceptor` has `addCacheMapping` method.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. `CacheControl.cachePrivate()` seems to set `private` to `Cache-control:` header.
But I found another problem. I want to set all of no-cache, no-store, and max-age=0 like nocache="true" in Struts. On the other hand, CacheControl.noCache(), noStore(), and maxAge() are all static method, and do not return this. So I cannot set all these headers via CacheControl...

Comment: Thank you for your information. To recap:
 - There is no XML out-of-the-box `Cache-Control: private` support in Spring 4.2+.
 - You can use `setCacheControl` to set `Cache-Control` header.
 - The `CacheControl` class in Spring have some design problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use an XML config (like I had to), you can achieve it as follows -

Create CacheControl bean in XML by first calling a factory method that creates the bean for you. In your case you need an empty CacheControl to start with -

```
<bean id="cacheControlFactory" class="org.springframework.http.CacheControl" factory-method="empty" />
```

Now invoke the `cachePrivate` method of the instance of `CacheControl` with the help of `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean` -

```
<bean id="myCacheControl" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref bean="cacheControlFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>cachePrivate</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now use the final bean holding your configuration, and invoke the `addCacheMapping` method of `webContentInterceptor`, and you're done. This config will apply to urls you send in as list in the varargs argument -

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <ref bean="webContentInterceptor"/>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>addCacheMapping</value>
        </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myCacheControl" />
            <list>
                <value>/home</value>
                <value>/dp/**</value>
                <value>/**/b/*</value>
            </list>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

A working xml configuration can be found in this SO thread - [How to set cacheControlMappings in WebContentInterceptor in Spring 5 Xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63559913/how-to-set-cachecontrolmappings-in-webcontentinterceptor-in-spring-5-xml)